# Deleting text from a LaTeX file with sed

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I'm trying to delete some lengthy passages from a LaTeX file by eliminating the text between two given strings. I've found a lot of advice that says to use `sed` for this, but I've run into some trouble figuring out the exact syntax to use. For example, I want to take this file:

```
\maketitle
\section{Part 1}
Here is some text
\section{Part 2}
Here is some more text
```

and turn it into this file:

```
\maketitle
\section{part 2}
Here is some more text
```

The trouble I've had is that sed gets confused by the backslashes. Should I be using an appropriate escape character, or is there a better solution?

Comment: "Should I be using an appropriate escape character." Why not? `\\ `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a *character class* to prevent interpretation of the slashes or you can further *escape* them, e.g.:

```
sed '/^[\]section[{]Part 1[}]/, /^Here is some text/d' filename
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ sed '/^[\]section[{]Part 1[}]/, /^Here is some text/d' dat/latex.txt
\maketitle
\section{Part 2}
Here is some more text
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\\maketitle/,/^\\section{Part 2}/{//!d}' file
```

Or if you want to delete a particular section:

```
sed '/^\\/h;G;/^\\section{Part 1}/!P;d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant that is quite simple, adaptable, and direct (e.g., there is no reference to anything besides the two section headers):

```
sed '/^\\section{Part 1}/,/^\\section{Part 2}/ {/^\\section{Part 2}/!d;}'
```

In a nutshell, this says: in the range of lines from the "Part 1" header to the "Part 2" header inclusive, delete all of them except for the "Part 2" header.